# Building error in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, malware, botnet

I am working on detection of botnets and want to create IDS by analysing the traffic patterns of botnets. For running the botnet: I got Zeus source code.

When I am building Zeus botnet 2.0.8.9 source code in Visual Basic 2010 (I am a newbie to Visual Studio),following errors occur.

[Errors During Building](http://postimg.org/image/6vixqak0r/c0688bb1/)

The errors appear to be quite simple,however i am completely unaware of how to fix it.When I click on an error, it opens Microsoft.CppCommon.targets file and error is highlighted as shown in figure and i donot know what to do.

[Microsoft.CommonCpp.targets](http://postimg.org/image/gd9yccvy5/76b1d03e/)

Kindly share your views for resolving the errors.

Comment: The paths to your config files are a bit of a mess. For example, they're not consistent even in the single error windows when they seem to need to refer to the same file. Check your configuration(s). Make sure you know the location and fully qualified path to the config file you need.

Comment: @PaulSasik exactly , but at which place in the project(in visual studio 2010) we need to update/change the location